# How to hide categories using xml and volusion API

Tags: php, xml, api, curl, volusion

I have a store in which I want to hide all those categories on bases of its products have. For this purpose i have local DB in which I save all the products and its categories. After all I have develop a script that I get the count of products in each categories.

Then I make XML and pass to API but unfortunately I am not success to hide categories while give value to the tag `<hidden>Y</hidden>`.

My XML sample is under.

```html
- <Categories>
  <categoryid>197</categoryid> 
  <parentid>134</parentid> 
  <categoryname>Test Category</categoryname> 
  <categoryorder>1</categoryorder> 
  <categoryvisible>1</categoryvisible> 
  <lastmodified>1/6/2016 8:52:00 AM</lastmodified>  
  <rootid>134</rootid> 
  <lastmodby>1</lastmodby> 
  <filtercategory>N</filtercategory> 
  <private_section_customers_only>N</private_section_customers_only> 
  <alternateurl_opennewwindow>N</alternateurl_opennewwindow> 
  <hidden>N</hidden> 
  <vcompareoptout>N</vcompareoptout> 
  <subcategory_displaycolumns_responsive>3</subcategory_displaycolumns_responsive> 
  <display_columns_responsive>3</display_columns_responsive> 
  <subcategory_displaymode2_responsive>0</subcategory_displaymode2_responsive> 
  </Categories>
```

Anyone please help me.